# mysql what is the right syntax for this conditional update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

MYSQL, what I want is like

```
update tablename 

case fieldA

when value1 then set fieldX0=xxx,fieldX1=bbb,fieldX2=ccc ...

when value2 then set fieldY0=yyy,fieldY1=eee,fieldY2=fff ...

end
```

what is the right and simple syntax for it? thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

It should be written this way:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldX = CASE WHEN fieldA = 'value1' THEN 'xxx' ELSE fieldX END,
    fieldY = CASE WHEN fieldA = 'value2' THEN 'yyy' ELSE fieldY END
WHERE fieldA IN ('value1', 'value2');
```

**Note that:** I wrote the `ELSE` part this way, because the default for the `ELSE` is `NULL` if the condition of the `CASE` expression is not valid, so this will set it to the original value not to the `NULL` value.

Comment: thank you, in this case ,use if is more simple,  I should make make my question more clear, If there are lots columns to be affected, is there a simple way to do it.

Comment: @user995789 unfortunately no, but you can build a temp table contains these values, then update with `JOIN`.

Comment: @user995789 here is [**a demo example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df61/1) for how to do that, note that, In this example I build the temp table in the fly in the same query but you can make a real temp table and do this query the same way.