# UPDATE query for multiple rows of same column

Tags: mysql

I have a database table and What I required to do is that,

I need to update the column with the column name 'Co15' of every rows according to the following conditions

> Co15 = SAMPLE if Co13 = 'c1' AND Col2 = 'b4'
>   Co15 = LIST if Co13 = 'c6'

Currently I am running each update query separately as follows

```
UPDATE tblname SET Co15 = 'SAMPLE' WHERE Co13 = 'c1' AND Col2 = 'b4';                                   

UPDATE tblname SET Co15 = 'LIST' WHERE Co13 = 'c6';
```

But wanted to know if there is any way where I could run only one update query all at once.

Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740557/mysql-what-is-the-right-syntax-for-this-conditional-update-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE tblname SET Co15=  
CASE
  WHEN Co13 = 'c1' AND Col2='b4' THEN 'SAMPLE'
  WHEN Co13 = 'c6' THEN 'LIST'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

***exactly getting the output to as following as:***

```
UPDATE tblname
    SET col5= CASE
        WHEN col3 = 'c1' AND col2 = 'b4' THEN 'SAMPL'
        WHEN col3 = 'c6' THEN 'LIST'
    END
```

***example: [sqlfiddle to click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b8b77/1)***

Comment: @user3462451, if this answer is working fine and clear your doubts you should refer this link and accept the answer....[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work]